# График plotly scatter - сохранить порядок данных по оси x

Tags: python, plotly, scatter

Если в параметре (size, color, или symbol) указать колонку 'play' сортирует ось x на графике.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['name1' , 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5'],
                     'it1' : [2, 2, 4, 6, 2],
                     'it2' : [2, 4, 4, 1, 4], 
                     'coeff_it' : [0.8, 0.9, 1.5, 1, 1.3],
                     'play' : ['Away', 'Home', 'Away', 'Home', 'Away']})

fig = px.scatter(df, x="opponent", y="it1",  symbol='play',
                 )
fig.show()
```

Comment: Круто! а вопрос в чем?

Comment: Так этого делать не нужно, нужно оставить без сортировки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну это такая фича plolty, многими принимаемая за баг. по умолчанию plotly [сортирует сет по категориальным данным](https://plotly.com/python/categorical-axes/). но это легко лечится:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['name1' , 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5'],
                     'it1' : [2, 2, 4, 6, 2],
                     'it2' : [2, 4, 4, 1, 4], 
                     'coeff_it' : [0.8, 0.9, 1.5, 1, 1.3],
                     'play' : ['Away', 'Home', 'Away', 'Home', 'Away']})
fig = px.scatter(df, x="name", y="it1",  symbol='play', color="play")
fig.update_xaxes(categoryorder='category ascending') # указываем явным образом
# порядок оси абсцисс.
fig.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]